# Select highest member of close coordinates saved in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe that has following columns: X and Y are Cartesian coordinates and Value is the value of element at these coordinates. What I want to achieve is to select only one coordinates out of `n` that are close to other, lets say coordinates are close if distance is lower than some value `m`, so the initial DF looks like this (example):

```
data = {'X':[0,0,0,1,1,5,6,7,8],'Y':[0,1,4,2,6,5,6,4,8],'Value':[6,7,4,5,6,5,6,4,8]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

> ```
>     X  Y  Value
> 0   0  0      6
> 1   0  1      7
> 2   0  4      4
> 3   1  2      5
> 4   1  6      6
> 5   5  5      5
> 6   6  6      6
> 7   7  4      4
> 8   8  8      8
> ```

distance is count with following function:

```
def countDistance(lat1, lon1, lat2, lon2):
    #use basic knowledge about triangles - values are in meters
    distance = sqrt(pow(lat1-lat2,2)+pow(lon1-lon2,2))
    return distance
```

lets say if we want to `m<=3`, the output dataframe would look like this:

> ```
>     X  Y  Value
> 1   0  1      7
> 4   1  6      6
> 8   8  8      8
> ```

What is to be done:

> ```
> rows 0,1,3 are close, highest value is in row 1, continue
> rows 2 and 4 (from  original df) are close, keep row 4
> rows 5,6,7 are close, keep row 6
> left over row 6 is close to row 8, keep row 8, has higher value
> ```

So I need to go through dataframe row by row, check the rest, select best match and then continue. I can't think about any simple method how to achieve this, this cant be use case of `drop_duplicates`, since they are not duplicates, but looping over the whole DF will be very inefficient. One method I could think about was to loop just once, for each of rows finds close ones (probably apply countdistance()), select the best fitting row and replace rest with its values, in the end use `drop_duplicates`. The other idea was to create a recursive function that would create a new DF, then while original df will have rows select first, find close ones, best match append to new DF, remove first row and all close from original DF and continue until empty, then return same function with new DF as to remove possible uncaught close points.

These ideas are all kind of inefficient, is there a nice and efficient pythonic way to achieve this?

Comment: How about sorting the data frame on a group of keys (latitude and longitude)? That way, you just need to compare with the immediately previous and the next pair of coordinates.

Comment: thanks for reply but coordinates can reach high values, m will be way higher than in example, there can be actually high number of close coords (tens), so this probably wont help

Comment: Will these be of any help ? https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/neighbors.html#nearest-neighbor-algorithms

Comment: @SivaKumarSunku will take a look at this tomorrow, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For now, I have created simple code with recursion, the code works but is most likely not optimal.

```
def recModif(self,df):
  #columns=['','X','Y','Value']
  new_df = df.copy()
  new_df = new_df[new_df['Value']<0] #create copy to work with
  changed = False
  while not df.empty: #for all the data
    df = df.reset_index(drop=True) #need to reset so 0 is always accessible
    x = df.loc[0,'X'] #first row x and y
    y = df.loc[0,'Y']
    df['dist'] = self.countDistance(x,y,df['X'],df['Y']) #add column with distances
    select = df[df['dist']<10] #number of meters that two elements cant be next to other 
    if(len(select.index)>1): #if there is more than one elem close
      changed = True
      #print(select,select['Value'].idxmax())
    select = select.loc[[select['Value'].idxmax()]] #get the highest one
    new_df = new_df.append(pd.DataFrame(select.iloc[:,:3]),ignore_index=True) #add it to new df
    df = df[df['dist'] >= 10] #drop the elements now

  if changed:
    return self.recModif(new_df) #use recursion if possible overlaps
  else: 
    return new_df #return new df if all was OK
```